# Error: The multi-part identifier "ccm.AnalysisSegment" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the above error when executing the following.

```
USE [DS]
GO

UPDATE [DS].[dbo].[ClientCodeMaster] 
SET ccm.[AnalysisSegment] = ccm1.AnalysisSegment
FROM [DS].[dbo].[ClientCodeMaster1] as ccm1
INNER JOIN [DS].[dbo].[ClientCodeMaster] as ccm ON ccm1.CLI_Ref = ccm.CLI_Ref
```

The two tables are identical, except ccm1 is a copy that has updated values.

What is going wrong?

All the other answers I looked at suggested [] were to blame. I've tried it with the USE removed, with the [DS] references removed and I get the same error. I've tried removing the [] from the AnalysisSegment column ID.  I even drag/dropped the column name from that table schema in case there was some weird control character snuck in.

Thanks :o)

Answer (score 0):

Write the query using the aliases correctly:

```
UPDATE ccm
    SET AnalysisSegment = ccm1.AnalysisSegment
    FROM DS.dbo.[lientCodeMaster ccm INNER JOIN
         DS.dbo.ClientCodeMaster1 ccm1 
         ON ccm1.CLI_Ref = ccm.CLI_Ref;
```

Your problem is that the alias on the left of the `SELECT` refers to the version of `ClientCodeMaster` in the `FROM` clause.  However, you have a *different* table in the `UPDATE`, which is causing the confusion.

Because SQL Server only allows you to update one table, just don't bother with that alias.

I have a strong preference for having the first table in the `FROM` be the table that is being updated, so I swapped the order of the tables.

Comment: Cheers. It didn't help in that the ccm1 table had been fudged with a stack of duplicate Refs which should be the primary key, they'd removed the primary key which let a load of dupes in.  I need to get my head round table instances... that's the problem with switching between Excel VBA and SQL at a moments notice, they're a totally different set of concepts.

Comment: @JohnnyC but that is another question... This, answers on your problem with running UPDATE statement and not using right syntax.

Comment: @JohnnyC . . . If you have another question, ask it as *another* question.  Modifying this one is rude because such changes can invalidate answers, which draws downvotes.